# On the Normability of Quasi-Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

N. J. Kalton wrote in his 1982 paper *Convexity Conditions for Non-Locally Convex Lattices* a statement that

*lattice 1-convexity is equivalent to normability*.

I cannot see why this is immediate. Kalton did not point to any reference of this statement neither.

Related notations are as follows.

$\|\cdot\|$ is called a quasi-norm on $X$ if $\|x\|>0$ for $x\in X, x\ne 0$, $\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha|\|x\|$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}, x\in X$, $\|x_{1}+x_{2}\|\leq C(\|x_{1}\|+\|x_{2}\|)$ for $x_{1},x_{2}\in X$, some constant $C>0$.

$X$ is said to be normable if there is a norm $\|\cdot\|'$ such that $c\|\cdot\|\leq\|\cdot\|'\leq c\|\cdot\|$ for some constant $c>0$.

$X$ is said to be $1$-convex if
\begin{align*}
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|\right\|\leq M\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|x_{i}\|
\end{align*}
for $x_{1},...,x_{n}\in X$, some constant $M>0$. Here we assume that $X$ has an order lattice and so $|x_{i}|$ is an element of the lattice space $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a hint somewhere else.

Consider
\begin{align*}
\|x\|'=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|x_{i}\|: x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}, x_{i}\in X\right\},
\end{align*}
then $\|\cdot\|'$ is a norm satisfying that
\begin{align*}
M^{-1}\|x\|\leq\|x\|'\leq\|x\|.
\end{align*}